# Big O(N) difference while using 2 different appraoches

Tags: c++, c, loops, big-o

My question is as follows:

I have a function to manipulate content of an array of MAX elements. This function will simply look like the following:

```
    //GLobal Variables
    uint8_t my_array[ MAX ];
    #define EMPTY 0xFF

    ...
    void initArray( void )
    {
        for( uint8_t i=0; i<MAX; i++ )
        {
             my_array[ i ] = EMPTY;   
        }
    }
    void manipulateArray( uint8_t value )
    {
        for( uint8_t i=0; i<MAX; i++ )
        {
             if( EMPTY == my_array[ i ] )
             {
                  my_array[ i ] = value;
                  break;
              }
        }
    }

    ...

    int main( void )
    {
         ...
         initArray();
         ...
         while( false == exit_flag )
         {
               manipulateArray( value );
               //get new value from user
               //update exit_flag based on new value
         }
         ...
         return 0;
    }
```

But then I thought that if I end up doing a lot of insertion/deletion, then i would be using for loops like crazy which is bound to affect the speed of the program or big O(N). So I thought what if I use another global

variable to keep track of where next empty sport in the array is for insertion instead of looping through it every time:

```
//GLobal Variables
uint8_t my_array[ MAX ];
uint8_t idx = 0;

...

void manipulateArray( uint8_t value )
{
    my_array[ idx++ ] = value;
}
```

Is my assumption here correct? Also is it true that it would be better to use another data structure in this particular case that is more suitable to the nature of operations (a lot of insertion & a bit-less deletion): vectors, linked lists...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Global variables; Eeek.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question you asked, but how can `-1 == my_array[i]` ever be true?

Comment: "Is my assumption here correct". Yes. "this particular case". What particular case? Without more detailed requirements of the overall goal it is difficult to assess what a good approach would be? More insertions? More deletion? No deletions? Random look up? etc...

Comment: The first version of the code sets every element that's currently equal to 255 to `value` (unless `MAX > 255` in which case it doesn't terminate). The second version sets one value of the array (index: 0, 1, ..., 255, 0, 1, ...) to `value`. It doesn't seem like they're the same at all.

Comment: @PaulHankin touche.

Comment: @PaulHankin These addition should clarify code

Comment: A complexity of O(n) is really not evil. However, it seems like you may better use a standard library collection class, such as a list or vector (your choice would change whether you mind or not about insertion or access complexity, or if you want to sort the list etc.).

Comment: the whole array can be initialized at the declaration to 0xFF.  Via: `uint8_t my_array[ MAX ] = {0xFF};`  Or if the `#define` is before the declaration then by: `uint8_t my_array[ MAX ] = {EMPTY};`

Comment: unless some of the (didn't post) code is setting elements of the array to 0xFF, then the function: `manipulateArray()` does not need to check if the specific element is 0xFF before getting a user input instead it could simply consist of the statement: `memset( my_array, value, MAX );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting you generally, I take you to be asking about the problem of "inserting" values be overwriting the `EMPTY` value, and of "deleting" values by replacing them with `EMPTY`.  In that context, you propose to maintain a global variable that tracks the next "empty" position, so as to avoid having to search the array for that position.

Indeed, if you know the location of the next position for insertion, then you can perform the insertion in O(1) steps, whereas if you need to perform a linear search, the best possible bound is O(n).  Maintaining metadata such as you propose is a perfectly good strategy if you will always be inserting at or deleting from the end of (the non-empty portion of) the array, for then you can maintain the auxiliary variable in O(1) steps, too.

But suppose you need to support deletions from arbitrary positions, without moving the other array elements, and you also want to be able to re-fill those positions with your insertion function.  In that case you have to solve a problem of maintaining information about where multiple empty positions are.  A single scalar variable is not enough, and relying on the array itself for that requires you to search the array for empty positions, which is back to where you started.

The alternative is to use a more complex data structure -- an array or a linked list, for example -- to track the openings in the main array.  In this way you could achieve O(1) complexity for any number of insertions and deletions at any positions in any sequence, at the cost of using O(n) *memory* to maintain the metadata about open array positions.  This is a classic space vs. speed tradeoff: implementing a faster algorithm requires using more memory, but you can conserve memory by using a slower algorithm.